# Apple SIP protection - can I add my binary to the protection

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, macos-catalina

I have a binary that I want to protect on him using the built-in SIP in MacOS,
How can I make SIP to protect on my binary?

Try to:

1. add `com.apple.rootless` as xattr to my file (didn't have permission to do it apparently)
2. read online who in apple can sign my binary with `com.apple.rootless` (didn't find anything)

Is it apple only?  only apple binaries can enjoy the SIP protection?
Is there any clever way to use it on my processes as well (disable sip, add my file to the sip protected path and re unable it, it's not good for me, I looking for a way that all my users will be able to easily install me)

Comment: I know that in Sierra e High Sierra, you can only do that in a disk other than the boot disk. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Can you explain how can I do it? or refer me please to a link with explanations?

Comment: You can set the attribute `com.apple.rootless` like this to any file that is not on the boot disk like this:

xattr -w com.apple.rootless 1 /Volumes/NonBootDisk/path/to/your/file

However, this won't help you with what you want, because it won't protect the file as intended. You can still send it to trash and edit it.

Comment: @jvarela any solution to add my self to SIP protected place?

Comment: As far as I know, that is only possible if you worked for Apple and had a signing certificate for that. If you have a paid developer account I would use a ticket to ask that to DTS if they could give a solution to your problem.